# Metamask private Key

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, metamask

i'm working on an Electron application with Metamask.
I need the private Key from the account in Metamask to use it in my application. Is there an easy way to get the private key imported into my application with an api call (with entering the password)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, because that would violate entire security model of metamask.